# one-dimensional array in shell not working for indexes greater than 08

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I have been wondering why the one-dimensional array in shell isn't working for the sub-script / index 08 and 09. How come this happen?

```
$ cat check

month_arr=(0 31 30 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31)
date="10/08/10" # dd/mm/yy format used here
IFS="/"
set  $date
echo ${month_arr[$2]}
```

See, when the subscript used is 08 and 09, then the below error is coming:

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/testing/shell$ ./check
./check: line 5: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

For values 00 to 07 the script is working. e.g. If in the script if I enter the month as 07, the output is:

```
ravi@ravi-Aspire-5315:~/Documents/testing/shell$ ./check
31
```

For those sub-scripts, i.e. 08 & 09, it's not working but it will work if I replace 08 with 8 and 09 with 9 in the month field.

```
$ cat check

month_arr=(0 31 30 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31)
date="10/8/10" # dd/mm/yy format used here
IFS="/"
set  $date
echo ${month_arr[$2]}
```

what is happening here?

Comment: Numbers with one leading zero is interpreted as octal numbers.

Comment: @Cyrus plz explain w.r.t. my findings. Why 07, 06 etc. are but but not 08 & 09?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force bash to use base 10:

```
echo "${month_arr[10#$2]}"
```

---

Numbers with one leading zero is interpreted as octal numbers. Octal system has no 8 and 9:

```
Octal 1 = decimal 1
Octal 2 = decimal 2
Octal 3 = decimal 3
...
Octal 6 = decimal 6
Octal 7 = decimal 7
Octal 10 = decimal 8
Octal 11 = decimal 9
Octal 12 = decimal 10
Octal 13 = decimal 11
```

Comment: I recommend you to expand this. Aparently the OP was not introduced to base or octal concepts.

Comment: yes it has worked properly. It's new for me what base and all. Can you provide me with any link / docs to refer and understand this concept of base and all.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes you are more or less right. I am new to this concept. I only knew that for `echo` command to interpret octal numbers etc., the octal number needs to be prefixed with a backslash `\`

Comment: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/binandhex.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have no words how to thank you. I had been using these number systems since a long time but today I came to know how they work after going through the link you sent. It is very simple but at the same time very much knowledgeable. These knowledge opens mind for a new way of thinking. Rui F Ribeiro, thank you again and again.

Comment: You are welcome. I was exposed to them many moons ago when working with assembly language, and in digital circuits subjects. Outside those realms, it is not that usual for people to be aware of the concept.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I was going through the link of number system. I am stuck at a place in that material. So, I have posted a Q for that here (http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51789/algorithm-to-convert-decimal-number-to-binary). May I request you to please look into the matter if you can take out some time. Sorry for troubling you.